# Query after rollbacking

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

Quick question, how to properly rollback transactions in Mysql?

I am learning transactions, its pretty new to me. PHP code:

```
query("START TRANSACTION");
if(!query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xxx ~~")) query("ROLLBACK");
if(!query("ALTER TABLE yyy ~~")) query("ROLLBACK");
if(!query("ALTER TABLE zzz ~~")) query("ROLLBACK");
query("COMMIT");
```

My question is, if it fails to alter table YYY, it will rollback,
but **will it try to alter table ZZZ after it**? Or one rollback mean it will ignore all other queries?

Should I fix my code somehow to prevent altering ZZZ in case YYY failed?

PS. `query() returns false if it fails, or true if it succeed`

Comment: Rollback applies to DML (ie UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE), not to DDL (ALTER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE, etc)

Comment: And even with DML, you don't simply rollback and then continue executing the other queries in the transaction series, you rollback and exit the sequence of queries